# Django - order existing search results according to user choices

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I'm creating a Django (1.8) web application that lets end-users search entries. I've managed to let users get search results according to their input.

However, I also want users to be able to order the search results after the results are returned, according to the user's selection of some choices (e.g. order by distance, order by rating, order by price). I'm having trouble implementing that because I can't figure out the logic behind this.

Could someone please tell me how to implement such feature please? Thank you very much!

Comment: just do .order_by('filedname')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is `.order_by('fieldname')`.
In your template you could have links to the same page which add GET parameters. In your view check for these parameters and decide how to sort the results.
It'll be somewhat like this

```
Model.objects.filter(field='value').order_by('sort-criteria')
```

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Comment: Hi Resley! Thank you for you reply last time! I encountered a little problem along the way. You said that in the template I could have links to the same page which add GET parameters. How do I obtained the URL of page that requested the new page in the view? I searched a lot of sources. Some people recommended using HTTP header referer. Is that the right direction? Thank you Resley!

Comment: `request.path` or `request.get_full_path()` will give you the path (i.e everything after the domain) of the current page. Usually this should be enough. `request.path` works in both the view and the template.

Generally for links to the same page directly passing the GET query is enough without any actual link, but I suggest looking up on correct practices that are followed.